# How are upgrades implemented in Cardano? CIP's?

Tags: decentralization, network, cip

Are upgrades to Cardano implemented via Cardano Improvement Protocols like Bitcoin? With the upcoming scaling upgrades such as increasing the block size, pipelining and input endorsers it seems that these upgrades are mainly being performed by IOHK/EMURGO. Are these proposals flagged by nodes/pools as yes/no and a fork created if some pools flag no to the proposal?

My question is concerned with decentralization and how it still seems like few entities are contributing/steering the way for the network compared to Bitcoin where some BIP's caused forks and separate chains because of disagreements on the BIP's.

For example with the block size increase. If there are nodes/pools that disagree with the proposal will we have a Cardano fork like Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash?

Answer (score 1):

Governance on the Cardano blockchain will come with Voltaire improvements at a a later date. Under the current system, update proposals are controlled by the keys IOG, CF and Emurgo control.

Block sizes are a protocol parameter and require signatures by the above 3 entities to take effect. Participants cannot control from a technical level these parameters; however they can influence them through discussions with the above entities.

Comment: I can't find who owns # of keys, and where is it documented?